# Memory leak issue on NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection

I have created a class to download images from web. Issue is there is a memory leak in it. Since this has been called multiple times. All the images getting downloaded are being called using this method. Since there are unlimited source of images the leak is mounting up.

Stack Trace is not showing any leak from code except **main**.

**Leaked Object:** Malloc  144, 176, 128, 160 bytes.

**Resposible Library:** CFNetwork

**Responsible Frame:** createCanonicalURL

**Stack Trace:**

```
   0 CFNetwork createCanonicalURL
   1 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::_createMutableCanonicalRequest(__CFAllocator const*, _CFURLRequest const*, void const*)
   2 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::_createCanonicalRequest(__CFAllocator const*, _CFURLRequest const*, void const*)
   3 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::copyCanonicalRequest()
   4 CFNetwork URLConnectionLoader::copyProtocolCanonicalRequest()
   5 CFNetwork URLConnectionClient::getRequestForTransmission(unsigned char, _CFURLResponse*, _CFURLRequest const*, __CFError**)
   6 CFNetwork URLConnectionClient::_clientWillSendRequest(_CFURLRequest const*, _CFURLResponse*, URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*)
   7 CFNetwork URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long)
   8 CFNetwork URLConnectionClient::processEvents()
   9 CFNetwork MultiplexerSource::perform()
  10 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
  11 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0
  12 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
  13 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
  14 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
  15 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
  16 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
  17 UIKit UIApplicationMain
  18 Interior News main /iPhone Ongoing Projces/WAN_Interiors/Latest_Interior_News_V_1_2/Latest_Interior_News/main.m:14
  19 Interior News start
```

connection object is properly released.

This is also coming in Device too. Most of them say its a bug in NSURLConnection, some say there is work araound adn some say not

I have tried setting as most mentioned

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
```

but no use...

Please advice

Code

```
if (connectionForImage==nil) 
    {

        NSString * fullImagePath = [rootURLForImage stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath];
        NSString * trimedstring = [fullImagePath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString * percentEscapedUrl = [trimedstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



        NSLog(@"Trimmed :%@",trimedstring);
        NSLog(@"PercentEscaped %@",percentEscapedUrl);

        NSURLRequest * imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:percentEscapedUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:6.0];

        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];



        connectionForImage =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:imageRequest delegate:self];


    }
```

Connection for image is getting released at connection did finish load and error.

Comment: Show your code...or Enable NSZombie...and run...

Comment: How does NSZombieEnabled help to trace leak

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using.

Comment: Enable NSZombie run and check Debug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried ASIHTTPRequest thenI encountered a badurl error. I checked the url It seemed to be of format http:/www.example.com instead of http://www.example.com later found out that the code

NSString * fullImagePath = [rootURLForImage stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath];
was the issue.

it was the one which was remoging the slash from http://
so changed my code to

```
 NSString * fullImagePath = [rootURLForImage stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath];
        NSString * trimedstring = [imagePath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString * percentEscapedUrl = [trimedstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSURL * rootURL = [NSURL URLWithString:rootURLForImage];
        NSURL * finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:percentEscapedUrl relativeToURL:rootURL];

        NSURLRequest * imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:60.0];

        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];



        connectionForImage =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:imageRequest delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

If 4.x and above just open your xcode and click option+command+R. It will open a window and then click on Add button and enter "NSZombieEnabled" and set the value to YES.

Comment: Why turn on `NSZombieEnabled` to debug leaks? Zombies help you find over-releases, not over-retains.

Comment: Can you explain more? NSZombieEnabled creates leaks on purpose (it prevents you from freeing NSObjects; that's how it works). How does it also help you find leaks? I've never heard of that.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` is a bit notorious for small leaks. If I'm reading your information correctly, it's about half a kB. Are you sure this is the cause of your memory problems? You may want to double check with heap shot and verify that you're not accumulating memory some other way. Not all memory accumulations will show up as leaks.

In my experience, if you use `NSURLConnection` and especially `UIWebKit`, you will generally have small (hundred byte at a time) leaks to contend with.

Comment: Not the few hundred bytes here and there. But this generally should not be a major impact (Cocoa has always had many small leaks). I would make sure that this is really the cause of your memory problems (if you have real memory problems, and not just a few blips on the Leaks instrument).